# Comparing 2 trace files using trace graph

Tags: graph, trace, ns2

I am using trace graph and I want to compare two different trace files with each other. The trace graph only works with one trace file. Is there any way by which I can compare two different trace files?
Is there any other trace analyzer(apart from trace graph) that can be used to compare two different trace files at the same time?
-Thanks in advance